# how to define a key binding that includes input to the minibuffer?

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer

I am frequently running multiple Emacs servers. When I am in a particular client I sometimes want to check which Emacs server I am connected to.

So I do:

```
`C-h v`
```

… and the enter in the mini-buffer `server-name`.

Is there a way to define a keybinding that also includes the input that should be entered in the mini-buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every key runs an Emacs command. You make an Emacs command (a special kind of function) then bind some key to it. For example, in your case, <kbd>C-h v</kbd> runs the `describe-variable` commands and takes `'server-name` as its argument, thus you can make a command for your need using something like:

```
(defun describe-server-name ()
  (interactive)
  (describe-variable 'server-name))
```

You can test this new command using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-server-name` <kbd>RET</kbd>, if you are happy with it, you can bind some key (for example <kbd>C-h C-s</kbd>) to it:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h C-s") 'describe-server-name)
```

---

Another way is using [(emacs) Keyboard Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html), I think minibuffer input is supported in vanilla Emacs. You can also fake the keyboard macro (which is a special kind of Emacs command) but I don't recommend this way:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h C-s") (kbd "C-h v server-name RET"))
```